Second screen not working
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I plugged a second screen, but it doesn’t work. When I do xrandr, I get:
(base) maria@PCGEC243:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 336mm x 210mm
1920x1200     59.95 +  47.96
1920x1080     59.95
1600x1200     59.95
1680x1050     59.95*
1400x1050     59.95
1600x900      59.95
1280x1024     59.95
1400x900      59.95
1280x960      59.95
1440x810      59.95
1368x768      59.95
1280x800      59.95
1280x720      59.95
1024x768      59.95
960x720       59.95
928x696       59.95
896x672       59.95
1024x576      59.95
960x600       59.95
960x540       59.95
800x600       59.95
840x525       59.95
864x486       59.95
700x525       59.95
800x450       59.95
640x512       59.95
700x450       59.95
640x480       59.95
720x405       59.95
684x384       59.95
640x360       59.95
512x384       59.95
512x288       59.95
480x270       59.95
400x300       59.95
432x243       59.95
320x240       59.95
360x202       59.95
320x180       59.95
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
1680x1050     59.95*+
1280x1024     75.02    60.02
1152x864      75.00
1024x768      75.03    60.00
800x600       75.00    60.32
640x480       75.00    59.94
720x400       70.08
DP-4-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
It seems that it recognizes the second screen (DP-4-1), but still no image. I also tried:
xrandr --output DP-4-1 --auto --right-of eDP-1

xrandr --output DP-4-1 --mode 1680x1050 --right-of eDP-1

But still no image. I saw some threads about similar problems but none of the solutions seemed to work. Any ideas?
